# trying to use cuda with go on windows

Tags: c, windows, go, cuda, cgo

There are various Go libraries that rely on the cuda.h file and the cuda library (specifically ML libraries).  Every time I try to install one of these libraries on Windows, I get an error saying

```
 fatal error: cuda.h: No such file or directory
 //#include <cuda.h>
```

I am aware of what I need to do (link the Cuda library/header files to the go library that I am trying to install), however, I am not sure how to go about doing this especially on windows. I am using GCC and not MSVC for various reasons, but even when I've tried using MSVC, I've had the same issues.

Is there some way that I can link the cuda compiler/header files directly to my Go env or do I need to manually point the go/cgo compiler to the directory holding the Cuda headers and how do I go about doing this?

I've tried asking a few of the developers who make these libraries for help but most of them are linux users so they don't really know.  An exhaustive google search has really lead me nowhere so I'm asking here.

Comment: Have you installed CUDA on your windows machine?  That would be the first step.  And if you intend to use CUDA, GCC is not an officially supported compiler. You should use MSVC.

Comment: Yes of course I have cuda installed on my machine.  MSVC also gives the same error.

Comment: If you use MSVC, then add an include path in the MSVC project to point to the directory where `cuda.h` is located.

Comment: its not working even if i point MSVC to the cuda includes folder. 

This is extremely annoying, I can use tensorflow and almost any other ML Library with Cuda but I can't get any golang libraries to compile.

Comment: If you have a MSVC project, and you have added an include path of something like `C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v8.0\include` (or wherever it is installed on your machine) then the project should be able to locate `#include <cuda.h>` properly.  Not sure what the issue is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find the answer.

The windows cuda installer installs things by default into a weird path:

```
C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v8.0\include
```

This path caused a lot of pain for the compiler as a result of the spaces in the folder names.  After reinstalling Cuda into `C:\CUDA\v8.0` and then appending my CFLAGS and LDFLAGS appropriately in my CGO file I was able to get things to run correctly.

For reference here are the CFLAGS and LDFLAGS that I used to get this to work:

```
//#cgo windows LDFLAGS:-LC:/cuda/v8.0/lib/x64
//#cgo windows CFLAGS: -IC:/cuda/v8.0/include
import "C"
```

This was with the github.com/chewxy/cu go library.  I also appended the new flags into that library in the cgoflags.go file because the maintainer did not have version 8 or version 9 in there already.  I mentioned this to him and he might update it later but for now that's what you have to do.

Comment: You may be able to work around the issue with the spaces by enclosing the paths in quotes, eg. `"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v8.0\include"`  This shouldn't be necessary if you're putting the path into a MSVS project "extra include paths" entry.

Comment: I was using GCC.  MSVS didn't really help much for what I was trying to do with this.  I swapped my go compilers to the MSVC toolbelt (and briefly tried LLVM as well) to see if the windows linker would work better with these types of issues but it didn't really seem like it (still was getting the same errors).  Perhaps, if I was building a library in cgo and not just in go this would be a potential solution, but honestly, it is just better in most cases to move the paths to something more simple.